# Windows: File List with Wildcard in filename

Tags: windows, powershell, file, command-line

Anyone can explain to me why?  From the screen shot, you can see I have some csv file in the current directory.  The command: dir *.csv or dir "*.csv" is not working correctly.  However, anything like: dir **.csv, dir ?*.csv, dir *.csv* are working.  All of them can list the files I am looking for.  Why?[image]

Comment: This is not a PowerShell issue. It's a user misunderstanding regarding what the file system expects, as you'd have this exact same issue using any shell (cmd.exe, PowerShell, Python, etc.). Try it. From PowerShell for a call to cmd.exe  `cmd /c 'dir D:\Temp\.csv'` or just open cmd.exe and do dir D:\Temp\.csv. The error will be `cmd : File Not Found,` Don't guess.  Always, always review the PowerShell help files and the built-in examples are your starting point. `Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full` or `Get-Help -Name GFet-ChildItem -Examples`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are unfamiliar with what dxiv is talking about. Aliasing in PowerShell is when you essentially give a command a nickname. In PowerShell there is no such command as `dir`, it's only an alias for the command `Get-ChildItem`.

The documentation for that command is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1

If you read through, you'll see that you need to specify a wildcard as a stand-in for the filename before passing the extension.

Generally speaking, the reason you need wildcards for things is to tell the language you're using that there should be something before it. By typing `.csv` you are searching for files that are literally called '.csv'. No more, no less. The wildcard in `*.csv` says that it should look for anything **ending** with '.csv'.